# How to change a background color for a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, frontend

I have this code
I need to do that
if {row.BB} <= 100 then show the row background that has this number as red color
how can I do this
This code connected to a database and it with a JSX file

```
    return (
        <>
            <Navigation />
            <Box bg={'white'} w="100%"
                 p={4}
                 m={4}
                 color="black"
                 rounded={'md'}
            >
                     <Table size='sm' variant='striped' colorScheme='gray'>
                         <Thead>
                             <Tr>
                                <Th>A</Th>
                                <Th>B</Th>
                                <Th>C</Th>
                             </Tr>
                         </Thead>
                         <Tbody>
                         {file.map((row, index) => (
                             <Tr key={index}> 
                                 <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
                                 <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
                                 <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
                             </Tr>
                         ))}
                         </Tbody>
                     </Table>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume 'bg' is used to give the background color of the row, which is also used for Box background color in your code.

```
<Tr bg={ () => this.getColorOftheRow(row.BB) } key={index}> 
    <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
    <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
    <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
</Tr>
```

**in component**

```
function getColorOftheRow(value) {
            if (value <= 100)
                return 'red';
            else if (value >= 100)
                return 'green';
                // add as many conditions as you want
            else
                return 'white';
        }
```

Comment: I need it just for the BB row not all the rows please if BB <= 100 change only the BB row background sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Tr represents the row and Td is column, Do you want to change the color of the column <Td >{row.BB}</Td> ?

Comment: I got one row has background red but I still have other numbers has values <= 100 on this column the background didnt change how I can make this code check all the number

Comment: is this because I have <Table size='sm' variant='striped' colorScheme='gray'>

Comment: thank you so much Abdur its working now, how I can add more condition on this but with OR for example bg={ (row.BB <= 100 ? 'red': 'white') } OR bg={ (row.BB >= 100 ? 'Green': 'white') }

Comment: better extract that logic into function and handle with if else or switch cases and that function returns the color as per rowBB value. e.g bg={()=>this.getColorOfRow(row.BB)}

Comment: are you able to write an example for that please

Comment: should I add this function inside the export default function ? sorry I'm just start learning those things

Comment: NP! add it in your component class, where your render function is present.

Comment: this will be in the same file correct? I have export default function xyz() then I have the return

Comment: Thank you Abdur everything working great

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear to me but still considering you want to change this row `<Td>{row.BB}</Td>` then, you can do that in two ways

1. Using If else block

`
{file.map((row, index) => (

```
if (row.BB <= 100){
    return (
        <Tr key={index} style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}> 
            <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
            <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
            <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
        </Tr>
    )
else {
    return(
        <Tr key={index}> 
            <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
            <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
            <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
        </Tr>
    )}
}
))}
```

`

2. If you are aware of ternary operator then you can simply use
   `
   {
   file.map((row, index) => (

   ```
    { row.BB <= 100 ? 
    (<Tr key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}> 
        <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
        <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
        <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
    </Tr>)
    : 
    (<Tr key={index}> 
        <Td>{row.AA}</Td>
        <Td>{row.BB}</Td>
        <Td>{row.CC}</Td>
    </Tr>)
    }
   ```

   ))}}
   `

**Please let me know if any of these methods works**

Comment: thank you so much what if I have one more condition BB >= 100 how I can add it on this

Comment: should I add any thing before the if it showing error after =>(

Comment: Add curly brackets if its giving error, and if you want one more condition then just add inside the if brackets like this if (row.BB <= 100 **||** row.BB >=100). Notice in this I have highlighted **||** because you can use **&&** as well which depends on your condition. Check  [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e/#ifelse) document if you are still facing problems

Comment: Thank you yes every thing is working good now, if this an int how can I add $ to the int number , if the row.BB return for example 10 how I can show it like 10$

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you could likely go about this, but I think the simplest way is to keep it simple (*since you are already using old school `<table>`s and `<td>`s anyway*).

You could do try something like this:

```
<Tr>
  ...
  <Td bgcolor={row.BB <= 100 && 'red'}></Td>
</Tr>
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: it showing error not sure why do we missing any Td> here ?

Comment: My bad! I was just typing really fast and forgot the closing </Td>. Of course you will need that! I edited my answer to have the closing tag as well.

Comment: If I need same thing but I need to add for that if BB <= 100 red  but if BB >= then green